# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute when i add data in list collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I want to add a new data into the list collection:

```cs
public void getRoles(string username, string UserID)
{
    var dbo = new DB_Layers.DB_Operations();
    var controllerActions = db.ControllersActions.SqlQuery(@"SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SiteControllers.ID ASC) AS ID,     SiteControllers.Name AS ControllerName, SiteControllersActions.Name AS ActionName FROM
                 SiteControllers INNER JOIN
                 SiteControllersActions ON SiteControllers.ID = SiteControllersActions.ControllerID INNER JOIN
                 RoleSiteContent ON SiteControllersActions.ID = RoleSiteContent.ControllerActionID INNER JOIN
                 AspNetRoles ON RoleSiteContent.AspNetRolesID = AspNetRoles.Id INNER JOIN
                 AspNetUserRoles ON AspNetRoles.Id = AspNetUserRoles.RoleId INNER JOIN
                 AspNetUsers ON AspNetUserRoles.UserId = AspNetUsers.Id
                 where Username = @username AND AspNetUsers.Id = @ID AND AspNetUsers.LockoutEnabled = 0 order by SiteControllers.Name", new SqlParameter("@username", username), new SqlParameter("@ID", UserID)).ToList();
    userRoles = new List<UserRoles>();
    for (int i = 0; i < controllerActions.Count(); i++)
    {
        var userRolesExist = userRoles.Where(x => x.ControllerName == controllerActions[i].ControllerName && x.ActionName == controllerActions[i].ActionName).ToList();
        if (userRolesExist.Count == 0)
        {
            userRoles.Add(new UserRoles() { ControllerName = controllerActions[i].ControllerName, ActionName = controllerActions[i].ActionName });
        }
    }
    //foreach (var controllerAction in controllerActions)
    //{
    //    userRoles.Add(new UserRoles() { ControllerName = controllerAction.ControllerName, ActionName = controllerAction.ActionName });
    //}

}
```

then I get this error:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

at this line

```cs
var userRolesExist = userRoles.Where(x => x.ControllerName == controllerActions[i].ControllerName && x.ActionName == controllerActions[i].ActionName).ToList();
```

Comment: I am struggling to see how you get that error with that code

Comment: You didn't show enough code or you tell us wrong error/line. Please refer to [mcve].

Comment: I can't test your code. I'm guessing the error happens because you are adding to the same collection you are iterating, `userRoles`.